# Does openGauss MOT purely in-memory table?

Tags: open-gauss

the Memory-Optimized-Table for openGauss is purely in-memory table? or it's can persist the data when data is larger that the server memory? or at least persist when server shutdown?

Comment: https://opengauss.org/en/docs/1.0.0/docs/Developerguide/mot-recovery-concepts.html

Answer (score 0):

MOT storage engine is a pure in-memory engine, so yes the whole data must fit into the memory. But MOT tables are strictly durable with persistence capabilities (redo log and checkpoint).

Answer (score 0):

The Memory-Optimized-Table for openGauss is an memory table.When the total memory usage is close to the selected memory limit.MOT no longer allows additional data to be inserted.But It can also persist data when the server is shut down(persistence capabilities).